# Use django text plugin for model fields in custom plugin

Tags: django, plugins, django-admin, django-cms

Hi this is a long shot i think but here goes.....

Basically i have a few custom plugins and apps being used in my django /django-cms site.  I have set tinymce up which is working fairly ok however what im wondering is it possible to use the built in text plugin for the TextField model fields in my custom plugins and apps?

so in effect the info text field for my main content plugin would actually render in the admin site as the text plugin

Like i said i think this is a long shot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use single-plugins on models, however you can define `PlaceholderFields` on your custom models to put cms plugins in. So you can define a PlaceholderField, put a TextPlugin inside that placeholder and do whatever you want.

For more information, read the official documentation about this http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/placeholders.html

Comment: Yeah thanks i have looked into this already, guess i was abit unclear, i think actually what im after is using the wysiwyg for my custom plugins that the text field uses that allows other plugins to be dropped in Like the default Text Plugin available in the admin

Answer (score 0):

I also had this requirement (formatted text on a django-cms plugin configuration) and ended up with the following workaround:
I installed [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce) and changed my TextField to an HTMLField in the CMS plugin configuration model. This will render a tinymce text editor in the plugin configuration form. You can then use the input from the HTMLField in your plugin template with the `...|safe` filter.